# aapt not finding

Tags: android

I have this problem in Eclipse. Did I install everything correctly?

```
Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe
```

I also have this problem:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.**main**);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(1);

    }
```

It seems that main in not known.

Comment: i think this is your first app in android..
setContentView is to be set to a layout designed in xml.
and findViewById has to be a view designed in the loaded content view layout.

Comment: 1. as my predessesor here says your code looks wrong, what's **main** ? findViewById(1) ? did you give any view the id 1 ?
2. when do you get this error ? did you try reinstalling the SDK and plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Go to the folder C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\ , do you the file 'aapt.exe'? If it's there, check that you have specified this location in Eclipse (Window -> Preferences, choose 'Android' in the left pane and verify that the 'SDK Location' is C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\  If this is all correct and you're on a computer using Windows, I know some people get errors when the 'android-sdk'-folder is inside 'Program Files'. This is probably due permission constraints in that folder. You could try to move the folder to another location. Remember to update the location in Eclipse if you do so.

Problem 2: As commented, setContentView is used to set a layout. I'm not sure if the stars are even legal to use. A valid name such as 'R.layout.main' refers to the file 'main.xml' in the folder 'layout' which can be found in the left pane of Eclipse.

Hope this helps.